# Execute Visual Studio Code Project automatically when laptop its turned off with external server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, server, automation, remote-server

I'm working on a project with Visual Studio Code, which executes some tasks automatically (eg: opens a website and reads its data and copies it to a google sheets document). My question was if there was any way to automatically run my project every day at dawn, that is, when my computer is not on, for example with an external server or something similar, I am not very clear.

Yes, I know that it can be programmed for a day and time with Windows Task Schedule and other applications, but it does not work with the computer turned off. That is why I had thought that I would have to create myself or make use of an external server.

Comment: Yes, you can do such a task with a server, providing it's up and running all the time.

Comment: @Teemu how can I do that? Could you explain me please?

Comment: That is not a programming question, you might ask about putting up a server and running a scheduled task at some other platform (ex. Quora), if your own search efforts are not benefical.